# I am solving the problem of saving and printing duplicate values ​in lists with Python, but I get the following error: How do I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x

```
# Input:
# - list_data_a: list of numeric or character values
# - list_data_b: list of numeric or character values
# Output:
# - long list of list_data_a and list_data_b is returned
# If the lengths are the same, the value of two list_data_a is returned.
# Examples:
# >>> import gowithflow as gwf
# >>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
# >>> b = [1, 2, 3]
# >>> gwf.comparison_list_size (a, b)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
# >>> b = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# >>> gwf.comparison_list_size (a, b)
# [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# '' '
# === Modify codes below =============
# You can write more than one line of code,
# Must be returned by assigning result value to result variable

list_data = [5, 10, 15, 20]
element_value = [5, 10, 58, 88]

for i in range(len(list_data)):
    if list_data[i] in element_value:
        list_data.remove(list_data[i])

print(len(list_data))
print('-----------')
print(element_value)
```

if list_data[i] in element_value:
IndexError: list index out of range
use list in a loop, is not it possible to use for i in range (len ()) to iterate over the size of list?
PS. Sorry I could not speak English ...

Comment: why do you have `i=+1`?? what is this supposed to mean? do you mean `i+=1`? even in that case, `i` is the iterator index, you do not need to add one to it. Please google how to write for loops in python

Comment: I get the same error when I erase it.
So I tried to add

Comment: are you trying to remove duplicated values?

Comment: the moment you use `.remove()` the length of your list has already changed. and thus there will be an index error

Comment: I solved it by resetting i = 0 under the loop! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
list_data = [5, 10, 15, 20]
element_value = [5, 10, 58, 88]

for i in list_data:
    if i in element_value:
        list_data.remove(i)
```